# Change frame of UITableView as per number of rows in cellForRowAtIndexPath in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, frame

I am resizing my UITableView as per its number of rows in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, that's why the next part of the UITableView was not visible, and for the part of the UITableView which is not visible, cellForRowAtIndexPath: is never called.

But I need to manage TableView frame according to number of rows, please suggest how can i implement this.
Thanks

Comment: you can use pagination for loading records into tableview as per you want

Comment: But i don't want to scroll tableviewcell, therefor i need to change the frame as per number of cell.

Comment: Have you used scroll view on top of UITableView to view whole tableview by scrolling ?

Comment: Yes, with some other UIViews and UIButton

Comment: @Arsad are section header/footer views and header/footer views of the table view itself not enough for your case?

Comment: @Losiowaty I am not used header and footer, I am just implemented the tableview height change according to cell should be add/ remove.

Comment: Is you requirement only to set the size of the `UITableView` based on the number of cells and a fixed height of each cell?

Comment: @Rikh Yes, same size

Comment: Yes, I get that, it's just unusual. The tableview itself has scrolling capabilities, and if you want to add custom views/buttons at the begining/end of the content you usually use `tableHeaderView` or `tableFooterView` properties of `UITableView`. It is usually easier that way, though your case may be different.

Comment: @Losiowaty I am disable the scrolling of table view because i need to all rows should visible not in scrolling and update table view frame according to number of cells. If i have update the frame then its not showing all updated rows and if i am not updated table view frame then cell is visible but its selection is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are using autoLayout**

To your `UITableView` add a leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint `>=`0. Also add a fixed height constraint with a priority of 750. Create an `IBOutlet` for this height constraint to your `UIViewController`. Now you can calculate your height using. This will allow your `UITableView` to only become scrollable once the total height exceeds your screen bounds.

```
//dataArray = array of your data source 
tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = dataArray.count * rowHeight;
```

Now this height constraint will break as soon as the `UITableView` becomes scrollable so if you are adding the ability to delete the rows, you will have to create a new height constraint to the `UITableView`as soon the number of rows of doesn't take up the entire screen bounds and update the new height constraint appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using UITableView's content size property .

```
[tableView reloadData]; // you need to reload data first before set frame
tableView.frame =CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x,tableView.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.contentSize.height);
```